# Mostrar en tabla fechas con formato dd/mm/yyyy y no mostrar los null

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, date, null

tengo un problema, tengo unas fechas guardadas en SQL en DATE, pero no logro que me salgan las fechas en formato dia/mes/año (con /),y tampoco logro que los null cuando hay una fecha que no existe no se me muestre.

Estoy usando MySQL, y los resultados de la consulta los muestro en una tabla.

A ver si me podéis decir como enfocarlo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El Dao que hago es el siguiente:

```
public ArrayList<Prestamo> selectPrestamo() throws Exception {
    ArrayList<Prestamo> prestamos = null;

    try (Connection connection = DBConnection.get()) {
        if (connection == null) {//si la conexión es nula lanza una excepción
            throw new Exception("Connection is null");
        }

        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM prestamo");

        prestamos = new ArrayList();
        while (rs.next()) {
            Prestamo prestamo = new Prestamo(rs.getInt("id"), rs.getString("DNIusuario"),
                    rs.getString("ISBNobra"), rs.getDate("Fechasolicitud"),
                    rs.getDate("Fechadevolucion"));
            prestamos.add(prestamo);
        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw ex;
    } finally {
        DBConnection.close();
    }
    return prestamos;
}
```

y esta es la hoja jsp

```
<%@page import="java.util.List"%>
<%@page import="Entidades.Prestamo"%>
<%@page import="DAO.DAOPrestamo"%>
<%@page import="Conexion.DBConnection"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<jsp:useBean id="prestamo" class="Entidades.Prestamo" />
<jsp:setProperty name="prestamo" property="*"/>



<%
String message = "";//por si hay que mandar un mensaje de error
List<Prestamo> prestamos = null;
DAOPrestamo dao = new DAOPrestamo();
try {

    prestamos = dao.selectPrestamo();

} catch (Exception ex) {
    message = ex.toString();

}

%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>formListarPrestamo</title>
    <link href="../css/estilos.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="titulo">
        <h1>BIBLIOTECA - PRESTAMOS</h1>
        <div id="menu">
            <div id="opciones">
                <h2><a href="../Menu.jsp">Inicio</a></h2> 
                <h2><a href="V2HojaPrestamos.jsp">Atras</a></h2> 
            </div>
            <form>
                <%if (!message.isEmpty()) {%>
                <input name="status_initial" type="text" style="width:400px" value="<%=message%>"/>
                <%} else { %>

                <br/><br/>

                <table border="1">
                    <tr>

                        <th>id</th>
                        <th>DNI Usuario</th>
                        <th>ISBN Obra</th>
                        <th>Fecha Solicitud</th>
                        <th>Fecha Devolucion</th>
                    </tr>
                    <!--creación de una tabla para mostrar todos los objetos prestamo-->
                    <%
                        for (int i = 0; i < prestamos.size(); i++) {%>
                    <tr>

                        <td><%=prestamos.get(i).getId()%></td>
                        <td><%=prestamos.get(i).getDNIusuario()%></td>
                        <td><%=prestamos.get(i).getISBNobra()%></td>
                        <td><%=prestamos.get(i).getFechasolicitud()%></td>
                        <td><%=prestamos.get(i).getFechadevolucion()%></td>

                    </tr>                            
                    <%}%>
                </table>
                <%}%>
            </form>
            </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inicialmente veo que es una pagina muy basica en JSP, de hecho no utilizas framework alguno, lo cual no está mal, supongo es un ejercicio académico... y seguiré por esa línea.

Dada la estructura de tu código, sugiero que implementes una clase utilitaria con un método estático que te permita convertir fechas al formato deseado y por otra parte retorne una cadena vacia en aquellos casos donde la fecha es NULL.

Para realizar la conversión de fechas al formato deseado lo propio sería utilizar la clase SimpleDateFormat, esta te permite armar un patrón bajo el cual se producirá la fecha sugiero leer la documentación para que lo tengas un poco mas claro (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

En principio el método podría ser algo así:

```
public static String FechaATexto(Date fecha) {
    if(fecha == null) {
      return "";
    }
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    return sdf.format(fecha);
}
```

Con lo anterio sería suficiente para logarar tu cometido simplemente en el JSP se deberá hacer un par de cambios como importar la clase utilitaria, y por otra parte utilizarla en la tabla, algo así:

```
<td><%= Utilidad.FechaATexto(prestamos.get(i).getFechadevolucion()) %></td>
```

Ahora, todo depende de a donde se quire llegar, podrías hacer algo mas genérico aun agregandole un parametro más a la funcion utilitaria, algo como esto:

```
public static String FechaATexto(Date fecha, String formato) {
    if(fecha == null) {
      return "";
    }
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(formato);
    return sdf.format(fecha);
}
```

Con este método podrás no solo pasarle la fecha sino también el formato deseado, así podrías reutilizar este utilitario en otras ocasiones. Así sería su uso:

```
<td><%= Utilidad.FechaATexto(prestamos.get(i).getFechadevolucion(),"dd/MM/yyyy") %></td>
```

Comment: Genial respuesta, he logrado lo que necesitaba, solo había que importarla, construir un objeto y luego añadirla en la columna.